# Am I wrong to mark this question as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[I have marked this question as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347780/keys-is-not-defined-in-angularjss-custom-filter-function). As I am not a user with high rep, I cannot see how many people have flagged this question as duplicate.

I saw some questions that was marked as duplicate within 2-5 minutes but this question was not. Therefore, it is seemed to me that perhaps I am wrong to mark this question as duplicate. I have also realized that sometimes it may take long time for some other reasons. But could not figure out the appropriate reason, that is why I am asking, should I stop from flagging this type of question as duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I wrong to mark this question as duplicate?

No, your flag was absolutely correct. Both questions ask the same thing about the exact same code. Textbook duplicate. I've voted to close as such.

> As I am not a user with high rep, I cannot see how many people have flagged this question as duplicate.

I don't know about flags, but there were no close votes by users with close vote privileges when this question was asked.

> I saw some questions that was marked as duplicate within 2-5 minutes but this question was not.

That doesn't mean much, loads of awful questions don't get closed as quickly as they should, and duplicates like this are often hard to identify.